# Vbscript GetObject Returns Unspecified Error

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vbscript and i'm writing an application to:

> - open internet explorer
>
>   - insert search text
>   - click search button
>   - get result count text

So far i have:

```
Dim obj

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "www.google.com"
WScript.Sleep 4000
IE.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "Test"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
WScript.Sleep 4000
Set IE = GetObject("","InternetExplorer.Application")
obj = IE.Document.All.item("resultStats").InnerText
MsgBox obj
```

However, if i run this i get the following error:

```
Error: Unspecified error
Code: 80004005
```

I don't know what could be wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The above error code mentions that the server failed to load application. Try different syntax of getobject method. However, would like to ask , why even are we using getobject method when we already have an object created of IE. Skip setting that IE object through getobject and try again.

Comment: it works thanks, i thought i had to get the object again.

Comment: Do not forget to upvote the comment :)